# How to *not* vertically center elements in button

Tags: css

There are a lot of questions about how to vertically align something, but I have the opposite problem: The elements in my button are vertically aligned, but I don't want them to:

```html
<button>
  <span class="c1">1</span>
  <span class="c2">2</span>
  <span class="c3">3</span>
</button>
```

The button has a fixed size, and the elements inside it should wrap around like in a normal `<div>` (but it has to be a button to be clickable and accessible).

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ge6opkha/) to experiment with. This is how it looks like, and how it **should** look like:

[image: alignment]

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: inherit;
}
  
.c1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.c2, .c3 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="c1">1</span>
  <span class="c2">2</span>
  <span class="c3">3</span>
</button>
```

Comment: `div` is not allowed inside `button`.  Only phrasing content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content

Comment: Padding causes whitespace, you can just remove it

Comment: Please first correct the HTML so it is valid - div not valid in the button currently.

Comment: I think wrapping other elements with button is not a good idea. We have many solution to make a `div` looks like and behave like a button with couple of css and js code.

Comment: @connexo thanks. I replaced the `<div>` elements with `<span>`s, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: changing the `button` to an `a` element fixes the problem

Comment: @Kokodoko the padding is not the issue. There are only 5 pixels of padding, it would not cause the elements to be vertically centered.

Comment: @thelonglqd I have learned that making a `<div>` behave like a button is generally a bad idea, because it isn't accessible.

Comment: You may argue that button functionality should always have a button element, for accessibility purposes

Comment: @Aloso: in some cases when you have a more complex structure inside, `div` is not such a bad idea because you need to change the default styling of the button. Btw, IMO, flexbox could fit your need.

Comment: https://karlgroves.com/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap out the internal `div` for a `span` so the HTML is correctly and validly structured.

Then use flexbox to layout the items.

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: inherit;
}

.c1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: gray;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.c2,
.c3 {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="c1">1</span>
  <span class="c2">2</span>
  <span class="c3">3</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This did the trick. So I guess `display: inline-block` simply does not work properly for button elements :(